# Client and Server public IP

Tags: server, network-programming, client, winsock

## Settings

- Router huawei HG532b configured to forward port = 50111 by enable NAT > DMZ and put
  Host address IP = 192.168.1.5 , and that is static IP of my PC in the Network.
- the router configured to forward port = 50111 by mapping the port by NAT > Port Mapping with following settings:

> Protocol = TCP/UDP, External port = 50111, Internal port = 50111,
> Internal host = 192.168.1.5, Remote host = 192.168.1.5, Mapping
> name=Chat.

- the router configured to forward port = 50111 by triggering the port by NAT > Port Triggering with following settings:

> Trigger protocol = TCP/UDP, Trigger start port = 50111, Trigger end
> port = 50111, Open start port = 50111, Open end port = 50111, Trigger
> name=Chat

- The router have public or external or WAN IP = 188.167.2.4.
- The router configured to enable UPnP.
- The router  configured  LAN > DHCP by make Start IP address = 192.168.1.6, End
  IP address = 192.168.1.253
- The router is my Gateway with IP = 192.168.1.1.
- My PC have static IP = 192.168.1.5, and the firewall service is off, and there is no antivirus installed or any other firewall, and I have XP with service pack 3.

## Problem:

I Created two programs, Client and Server, they are parts of the chat program.
Server's socket have LocalPort = 50111 and put to Listen mode.
Client's socket have RemotePort = 50111, and have text box to put  the remote IP in it and Command button called **Connect**.

- When I test the Client and Server in the same PC that have Static IP = 192.168.1.5 and put  the remote IP in Client  = 192.168.1.5, everything go fine.
- When I test the Server in the PC that have Static IP = 192.168.1.5  and put  Client  in PC with IP = 192.168.1.9 and put the remote IP in Client = 192.168.1.5, everything go fine.
- When I test the Client and Sever in the same PC that have Static IP = 192.168.1.5 and put  the remote IP in Client = 188.167.2.4 (that is my router public or external or WAN IP), and press **Connect**, the winsock error  "connection is forcefully rejected" is raised.
- When I test the Server in the PC that have Static IP = 192.168.1.5  and put  Client  in PC with IP = 192.168.1.9 and put the remote IP in Client  = 188.167.2.4 (that is my router public or external or WAN IP), and press **Connect**, the winsock error "connection is forcefully rejected" is raised.
- When I test the Server in the PC that have Static IP = 192.168.1.5  and put  Client  in PC in another network with IP = 192.168.1.7 and put the remote IP in Client  = 188.167.2.4 (that is my router public or external or WAN IP), and press **Connect**, the winsock error timout is raised.

I read that if the Client and Server in the same PC, setting the Client remote IP to public or external or WAN IP will not work.

I read that the XP with service pack 3 have issue with port forwarding.
I read that there is a technique called hole punching, that can round over router port forwarding or firewall.

I want an expert to explain to me, what is wrong and how to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your tests you are experiencing problems from with out side your own private network.  There are two possibilties that could be giving you problems and its more likely to be your port forwarding thats causing the issue

**1: Port forwarding && DMZ**
DMZ is something you don't want in this case as thats another layer of security on top of the security thats all ready active on your router and will give you those rufused connections. Look at the following page on how to set up port forarding
http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Huawei/HG532b/Xbox_Live_360.htm

Setup the one rule with the following information
External port: 50111
Internal port: 50111 
Internal host: 192.168.1.5
Protocol: This can be set to TCP/UDP, if you are using both in your application then thats fine but if you are using just the one then best to set this to the one your are using.

**2: External IP**
From time to time your router will drop connection  from the internet and re-connect and on occasions your external ip address can change, check with https://www.whatismyip.com/ to see if the ip address has changed. If you are looking for the bigger picture with your application then may be worth looking into getting dynamic address, have a look at this for more information http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/what-is-a-dynamic-ip-address/

Hopefully this helps you